# Search for pattern - filling model

Tags: java, design-patterns

im writing a java application where i have to fill plain objects with values.

example object

```
public class A {
    private String a;

    private String b;

    // ...

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    // ...
}
```

i fill it like this

```
public class Initalizer {
    public A init()  {
        A a = new A();

        a.setA(// get it from somewhere
        );
        a.setB(// get it from somewhere
        );
        // ...

        return a;
    }
}
```

in this case, i get the values from jsoup, a html-parser

**my question is:**
is there a more elegant way? like defining one method for filling one property. like in lego where one stone fits the other.

is there a design-pattern i don't know?

thanks for help

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 0):

Yes there many design pattern that matches your need. Those patterns are called     **Creational Patterns** like :

**Factory Pattern :**

> Factory pattern is one of most used design pattern in Java. This type
>   of design pattern comes under creational pattern as this pattern
>   provides one of the best ways to create an object.

For more complex object building there is also the **Builder Pattern** :

> Builder pattern builds a complex object using simple objects and using
>   a step by step approach. This type of design pattern comes under
>   creational pattern as this pattern provides one of the best ways to
>   create an object.

You can find more [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) with examples.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. i already use the factory pattern for this (its the initializer in my example). but i don't like call 20 setters by hand.

Comment: Anyway I think for your example Factory is the best but there is also the builder (for complexe object building) and prototype design pattern (if you care about perormance) .. plz check the reference in the answer for more example and use cases

Answer (score 0):

There is a pattern called Builder Pattern which helps you chaining the methods for building up the object.

```
public class A {
    private String a;

    private String b;

    // ...

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public A setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
        return this;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public A setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
        return this;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
public class Initalizer {
    public A init()  {
        return new A().setA(...).setB(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest though is a builder pattern approach. It's little bit of modification of yours. This is a very good resource to get a deeper understanding of this pattern [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/builder-design-pattern-in-java.html)

```
public class A {
    private final String a;
    private final String b;

    public static class builder {
        private String a;
        private String b;

        public Builder a(String a) {
            this.a = a;
            return this
        }

        public Builder b(String a) {
            this.b = b;
            return this
        }

        public A build() {
            return new A(this);
        }
    }
      private A(Builder builder){
          this.a = builder.a;
          this.b = builder.b;
   }
}
```

And you will initialize your class in this way;

```
A a = new A.Builder()
           .a("string")
           .b("string")
           .build();
```